# WebSphere Technology Stack vs Oracle WebLogic Stack

Tags: websphere, weblogic, ibm-mq

We currently have the following technology stack, that we are very happy with:

```
IBM Edge Servers
IBM HTTP Server
WebSphere Application Servers 6.1 (EOL Sep 31st)
WebSphere MQ Series
Oracle Database + Some DB2 databases.
```

Our organization is about to sign a company wide unlimited license agreement with Oracle and we wondering the benefits to our stack for our web apps. So being a non Oracle dude what would be the non - IBM stack for this setup?

```
Does Oracle provide an equiv edge server
Apache HTTP Server?
WebLogic Application Server 10.3
Messaging Backbone? 
Oracle Databases.
```

Thanks

Comment: Love the all-you-can-eat licensing trick.  The idea is to get you to deploy the technology everywhere. Then when the license term ends, you are forced to license everything and the negotiations start with then-current retail.  Also, you probably deploy the web app server and HTTP server on different nodes.  Last I checked, IBM includes both in the price of one WebSphere ND license regardless of where the components are deployed. You might want to check how that is licensed once the all-you-can-eat term expires.